# I am getting a weird error unauthorized changes blocked controlled folder access blocked OMApSvcBroker.exe . Do you think it is some sort of virus?

Tags: windows-11, virus, malware, msi-laptop

Here is the image below:

[image]

I have run windows defender multiple times nothing shows up. I also ran RKill + Malwarebytes ADW cleaner + Hitman pro
removal programs. The only thing I have not done in a while is a factory reset.

Now I am getting this error:

[image]

Comment: What exactly is your question? You have controlled folder access enable, that’s what is preventing, Firefox from making changes. I see no direct evidence of malware activity OMApSvcBroker.exe belongs to MSI software.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have this *enabled*:

[image]

To get rid of the pop-ups click 'Click to see settings'.

The assumption the cause is a virus is incorrect, it's part of protection against unauthorized changes by a virus, ransomware etc..

Comment: So I assume you are assuming this is the etc and not a virus ransomware ?\

Answer (score -2):

Uninstall Dragon Center, MSI Center and MSI Center (If you have them) and do a clean reinstall of the software.
Btw yeah, don't worry because there is a very small chance that it is malware.

If this still happens, install a different piece of antivirus software (I recommend Kaspersky free and Avast One Free). This will disable controlled folder access and in turn stop you from getting those notifications.

You can also contact microsoft support and they will probably fix the  issue. I would NOT advise you to factory reset as you will lose all of your data and I would think that you would want to avoid that

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).